# How to enable linting for flake8 plugins in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, flake8

I am having flake8 installed and VSCode is able to detect default checks with the squiggly lines. Now, I installed `flake8-docstring` but VSCode is not warning on missing docstring.

For example, running below command in powershell, gives expected output.

```
>> python flake8 abc.py
abc.py:1:1: D100 Missing docstring in public module
```

But in VSCode, it is not showing the squiggly lines.

Answer (score -1):

In VSCode, press `Ctrl + Shift + P`, and type *Select Linter*:

[image: Select Linter]

Then select the linter of your choice, e.g  `flake8`:
[image: Choose linter]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Author asks to enable flake8 plugin in VSCode, not the default package

Answer (score -1):

Different linter will produce different effects, it is recommended that you use `pylint`.

1. First enable linting

   [image]
2. Then select pylint

   [image]
3. Effect

   [image]